# Use part of non static file name to create new directory

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to figure some stuff out.

I'm already learning to use the `shutil.copy`, `.move` functions as well as scanning files with `glob`. However I have a few questions on a scenario I'm facing:

Find a file that gets deposited to the same directory everyday, but in which half the file name changes everyday,and use it to make a destination folder, or zip it up with `zipfile`.

Example:

- File `X110616.Filename_110416.txt` comes in today.
- Tomorrow it will be `X110616.Filename_110423.txt`.

Since half or part of the name changes everyday, how do I cut/save a specific part of the string for a function or module to create a destination folder, or a zip file?

I can use the `glob` module to scan for a file with wild card variables, and I've tried using the `rstrip()`, but that only seems to remove the last half and not the beginning or center of the string.

Also not sure how to save the variables it finds and use it else where to create directories or zip files. Bottom line is I know how to tell the script to look for non-static characters in string but not sure what direction to take it in when using/saving those characters for other things:

```
import glob

    for f in glob.glob("C:\\users\%username%\\Documents\\Test_Files\\X??????.Filename_??????.txt"):
        Newdir = f
        print(Newdir)
        #or use to make a directory, or zip file...
```

This will find me the file with any ending, however I can't seem to understand how to save the file's name or path (whatever it may be).

Answer (score 0):

To get a substring in python you use the slice operator.

```
>>> a = "Hello World"
>>> a[0:5]
'Hello'
```

str.split is also very powerful.

```
>>> a.split(" ")
['Hello', 'World']
```

I will often solve problems like you describe with a combination of the two. But for really tricky parsing problems there are regular expressions.

```
>>> b = "whatsit__blah.foo"
>>> import re
>>> result = re.search("(?P<first>[a-z]+)__(?P<second>[a-z]+).(?P<ext>[a-z]+)", b)
>>> result.groups()
('whatsit', 'blah', 'foo')
>>> result.groups("first")
('whatsit', 'blah', 'foo')
>>> result.group("first")
'whatsit'
>>> result.group("second")
'blah'
>>> result.group("ext")
'foo'
```

As you can see there is a lot to regular expressions. Because of the added complexity I avoid them unless I have a very complex problem.

Two more functions you may find useful. The os.path module has .split(), which will split a path into the base directory and the filename and  .splitext(), which will split a path on the last ".", return the extension and the remainder of the path.

Comment: Great! I'll have to try this. But if the file I want to use is in a directory other than where the script is, I still need to give the filepath, correct? (i.e., a = "C:\\Users\%username%\\documents\\dxxxx.xxx.xxx"), a=[14:19] = dxxxx

Comment: You may also find os.path.split useful to split the filename off of the path.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I ended up doing, and it seemed to have worked. It made a folder for each file that was found in a specific directory, while only using a specific part of the file name to make a folder reflecting the filename.

```
destdir = "C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Documents\\Test_Files\\test\\"
srcpath = "C:\\download\\"   
 for z in os.listdir("C:\\download"):
    if z.endswith("FILE.FILENAME.ZIP"):
        os.mkdir(destdir + z[0:7])
        newdir = destdir + z[0:7]
        print(newdir)
```

I added print at the end to show what it created.